# PDF embedded with <object> acting odd

Tags: html, object, embed

I am trying to embed a pdf in a web page.  I am using the following code:

```
<object data='pdf/main.pdf#nameddest=fun&view=FitH' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='740' 
        height='800'>
```

This works in chrome(apart from FitH doesn't work) and firefox and ie for me.  However, when viewing on a mac it doesn't work with named destinations(just loads to the top of the pdf if Safari).  Also, it doesn't seem to work in Firefox as firefox seems to have disabled adobe plugin by default.  Is there a better way to embed a pdf with relative ease and wide compatability?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach at the moment is to use [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) You can check out the demo here : [Demo for pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) and download the source from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

It is by mozilla and very widely supported / used.